# Can I compile the java code in something like a dll to use inside the Python code, and use this before in a pyinstaller compiled program?

Tags: python, java, dll, compilation, programming-languages

I want to use a [Java project](https://github.com/wmixvideo/nfe) inside Python, I read that [some Python libraries do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python). But my question is it: If I do it, can I compile before all the code with pyinstaller or can I **compile the java code in something like a `dll` to use inside the Python code, and use this before in the compiled program?**

If somebody can reply, I have another doubt too, if don't have a way to do **it** with Java, have a way with another language, like PHP?

**EDITED:**

Send me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262603/is-there-any-way-to-compile-java-code-into-a-dll), but its out of date... I try to use the first answer, `ikvm`, but I receive this error because the version of java:

`ikvm-7.2.4630.5\bin>ikvmc -target:library -out:nfe-4.0.30.dll -recurse:./nfe-4.0.30.jar`

> Warning IKVMC0108: not a class file "cc/mallet/util/tests/TestPriorityQueue$1.class", including it as resource    (class format error "51.0")

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875231/converting-java-to-net-library-using-ikvmc-warning-ikvmc0108-not-a-class-fil)

Because the tip from @StephenC, I try to change the command:

`ikvmc -target:1.7 -out:nfe-4.0.30.dll -recurse:./nfe-4.0.30.jar`

I receive this error:

> fatal error IKVMC5009: Invalid value '1.7' for -target option

**EDITED 09/05:**

The links don't help me to convert the library to Python. I don't know Java, and don't know what the Java version from the project that I provided. Please, if somebody know a updated way to convert newest Java libraries to Python, I thank.

Comment: The duplinks (taken together) should explain how to create a DLL from Java code that you can use from Python.  But there are other ways to call Java code from Python that you may also want to research.

Comment: Really? What the another way that you recommend me?

Comment: Because I want a closed code, and I don't know if have a way to convert the two code together

Comment: *".... that you may also want to **research**."*.  Google it.

Comment: Re: the "class format error 51.0" - Yes, one of duplinks specifically says that IKVM only supports Java 7 and earlier!  (It is important to read Q&As carefully.) You could try recompiling your code with a Java 7 compiler, or the Java 8 compiler using the `-target 1.7` option.

Comment: I receive another error, I'll edit my question and put how I'm doing it

Comment: The `-target` option is for `javac`.  You (would) need to rebuild all of your classes (and 3rd party library classes) for the Java 7 platform ... THEN use `ikvm`.  (I say "would".  I haven't done this myself.)

Comment: I undestand, I can't do it, for a lot of reasons, but principally because I don't know java, I only wanted to use this library in my python code, because this library is bestest that python libraries that do the same thing.

Comment: Well ... maybe the answer is "there is no way to do it" that will work with current versions of Java.  Compiling Java libraries to DLLs is a pretty hairy idea.